# app to app alexa account linking starting from website

Tags: login-with-amazon, alexa-account-linking

i am implementing alexa account linking starting from my website to receive notification on my alexa device, using the LWA flow as shown on the documentation https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html#alexa-url-parameters.

But i get invalid scope error for the scope "alexa::skills:account_linking".

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the client ID in the skill itself, you can find it in the permissions tab below Account Linking in your smart home skill.
It is a Login with Amazon(LWA) profile in itself.

Answer (score 0):

refer to: [Alexa Account Linking - "Invalid account linking credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103791/alexa-account-linking-invalid-account-linking-credentials/68061902#68061902)

Mistakes -

1.Creating a new LWA (Login with Amazon) Profile.
You don't need a new LWA profile, you should instead use the Alexa credentials under the permissions tab on the skill page. They have the right scope (alexa::skills:account_linking) required for App-App Linking and LWA profiles cannot have this scope.

2.Using a development version of a live skill.
I had modified the account linking section in a development version to point to a test deployment. Although these changes are permitted in the developer console, account linking failed every time, so I created a new skill.

3.Reusing the Alexa Auth Code.
I had not realized that even a single bad request will invalidate the Alexa Auth Code.

4.Logging into the wrong Alexa Account.
When you get to the LWA screen during testing the account linking, only login with the developer credentials in which the skill is created. This is because at this point the skill is only available to the Alexa developer account and not anyone else. (Not even the beta testers)